# How do I get the table schema/columns from an entity object in cakephp 3?

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0

Let's say I have a bonified `\Cake\ORM\Entity` object -- `$kablammo`  I can confirm and make sure it has an associated repository by doing the following:

```
use Cake\ORM\Entity;

// ..snip

if ($kablammo instanceOf Entity && !empty($kablammo->source())) {
    $repository = $kablammo->source();
    // ... what do I do here to get the table schema info/columns?
}
```

I'd like to be able to view the table columns for this Entity's associated table basically.  What's the best way to do this?  Am I going about it wrong already?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think I figured it out.

```
use Cake\ORM\Entity;
use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;

// ..snip

if ($kablammo instanceOf Entity && !empty($kablammo->source())) {
    $repository = $kablammo->source();
    $table = TableRegistry::get($repository);
    debug($table->schema());
}
```

At least I'm on the right track now.

Comment: I'm dumb.  This was pretty obvious.  Maybe this will help someone else though.

Comment: For a table if anyone needs it : use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;
 $table = TableRegistry::get( 'my_table_name' );
  $table->schema()->columns();

Comment: and if I would like to get the hidden fields of the Entity?